# error 1064 while forwarding engineer my schema

Tags: mysql

i want to forward engineer my base but i get this error all over again. Here is my sql code and next is the error screen i get:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema imdb_schema
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema imdb_schema
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `imdb_schema` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`Multimedia`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`Multimedia` (
  `id_multi` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title_multi` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `category` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `release_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `language` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `country_origin` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `official_website` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `plot` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
  `bloopers` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
  `technical_characteristics` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `trailer_url` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `soundtrack` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_multi`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_multi` (`id_multi` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`Registered_Users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`Registered_Users` (
  `email` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `profile_picture` LONGBLOB NULL,
  `gender` VARCHAR(45) BINARY NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = '             ';


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`VideoGames`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`VideoGames` (
  `Console` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_multi` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_multi`),
  CONSTRAINT `id_multi`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Multimedia` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`TV_Series`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`TV_Series` (
  `tv_station` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `episode_number` INT NOT NULL,
  `season_number` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_multi` INT NOT NULL,
  `serie_duration` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_multi`),
  CONSTRAINT `id_multi`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Multimedia` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`Episodes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`Episodes` (
  `episode_number` INT NOT NULL,
  `season_number` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`episode_number`, `season_number`),
  CONSTRAINT `id_multi`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`TV_Series` ()
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`Premium`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`Premium` (
  `email` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `subscription_duration` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `occupation` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email`),
  CONSTRAINT `email`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Registered_Users` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`Prof_Profile`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`Prof_Profile` (
  `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `surname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `DOB` DATE NOT NULL,
  `profile_picture` LONGBLOB NULL,
  `personal_url` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`, `surname`),
  CONSTRAINT `email`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Premium` ()
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`Comments`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`Comments` (
  `email` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `id_multi` INT NOT NULL,
  `comment_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `comment_text` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email`, `id_multi`),
  INDEX `fk_Registered_Users_has_Multimedia_Multimedia1_idx` (`id_multi` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Registered_Users_has_Multimedia_Registered_Users1_idx` (`email` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Registered_Users_has_Multimedia_Registered_Users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`email`)
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Registered_Users` (`email`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Registered_Users_has_Multimedia_Multimedia1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_multi`)
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Multimedia` (`id_multi`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`Rates`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`Rates` (
  `email` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `id_multi` INT NOT NULL,
  `rating` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email`, `id_multi`),
  INDEX `fk_Registered_Users_has_Multimedia_Multimedia2_idx` (`id_multi` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Registered_Users_has_Multimedia_Registered_Users2_idx` (`email` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Registered_Users_has_Multimedia_Registered_Users2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`email`)
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Registered_Users` (`email`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Registered_Users_has_Multimedia_Multimedia2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_multi`)
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Multimedia` (`id_multi`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`Contributes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`Contributes` (
  `email` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `id_multi` INT NOT NULL,
  `type_contribution` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email`, `id_multi`),
  INDEX `fk_Registered_Users_has_Multimedia_Multimedia3_idx` (`id_multi` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Registered_Users_has_Multimedia_Registered_Users3_idx` (`email` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Registered_Users_has_Multimedia_Registered_Users3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`email`)
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Registered_Users` (`email`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Registered_Users_has_Multimedia_Multimedia3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_multi`)
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Multimedia` (`id_multi`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`Personal_List`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`Personal_List` (
  `list_tittle` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_multi` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`list_tittle`, `id_multi`),
  CONSTRAINT `email`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Registered_Users` ()
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`List`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`List` (
  `id_multi` INT NOT NULL)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`Award`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`Award` (
  `award_institution` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `award_title` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `award_year` YEAR NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`award_institution`, `award_title`, `award_year`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`Cast`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`Cast` (
  `id_cast` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `surname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cast`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`Crew`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`Crew` (
  `id_crew` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `surname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_crew`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`Stars_in`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`Stars_in` (
  `id_cast` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_multi` INT NOT NULL,
  `role` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cast`, `id_multi`),
  INDEX `fk_Cast_has_Multimedia_Multimedia1_idx` (`id_multi` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Cast_has_Multimedia_Cast1_idx` (`id_cast` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Cast_has_Multimedia_Cast1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_cast`)
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Cast` (`id_cast`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Cast_has_Multimedia_Multimedia1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_multi`)
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Multimedia` (`id_multi`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`Occupation_Categories`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`Occupation_Categories` (
  `title_occuption` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`title_occuption`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`Takes_part`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`Takes_part` (
  `id_crew` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_multi` INT NOT NULL,
  `title_occupation` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_crew`, `id_multi`, `title_occupation`),
  INDEX `fk_Crew_has_Multimedia_Multimedia1_idx` (`id_multi` ASC),
  INDEX `title_occupation_idx` (`title_occupation` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Crew_has_Multimedia_Crew1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_crew`)
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Crew` (`id_crew`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Crew_has_Multimedia_Multimedia1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_multi`)
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Multimedia` (`id_multi`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `title_occupation`
    FOREIGN KEY (`title_occupation`)
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Occupation_Categories` (`title_occuption`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

ERROR SCREEN:

> Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near ')
>       REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Multimedia` ()
>       ON DELETE CASCADE
>       ON UPDA' at line 9

SQL Code:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`Movies`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`Movies` (
  `id_multi` INT NOT NULL,
  `movie_duration` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_multi`),
  CONSTRAINT `id_multi`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Multimedia` ()
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed
>
> Fetching back view definitions in final form. Nothing to fetch
>   Executing SQL script in server SQL script execution finished:
>   statements: 6 succeeded, 0 failed
>
> Fetching back view definitions in final form. Nothing to fetch
>   Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near ')
>       REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Multimedia` ()
>       ON DELETE NO ACTION
>       ON UP' at line 9

SQL Code:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`VideoGames`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`VideoGames` (
  `Console` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_multi` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_multi`),
  CONSTRAINT `id_multi`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Multimedia` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed
>
> Fetching back view definitions in final form. Nothing to fetch
>   Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near ')
>       REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Multimedia` ()
>       ON DELETE NO ACTION
>       ON UP' at line 9

SQL Code:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `imdb_schema`.`VideoGames`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imdb_schema`.`VideoGames` (
  `Console` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_multi` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_multi`),
  CONSTRAINT `id_multi`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `imdb_schema`.`Multimedia` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed
>
> Fetching back view definitions in final form. Nothing to fetch

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I can't find where the error is located. When i try to correct the error, another one is poping up and prevents me from moving on and forward engineer my schema. Any ideas on how i can fix it?

Comment: What happens when you run the table queries one at a time?

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY () REFERENCES imdb_schema.Multimedia ()` You have several of these faulty, incomplete FK definitions with empty `()`. They must reference columns specifically: `FOREIGN KEY (id_multi) REFERECES Multimedia (id_multi)`

Comment: And in this context `CONSTRAINT id_multi`, the `id_multi` is the _constraint name_, not the column name referenced. It will need a different name like `CONSTRAINT fk_id_multi` or you'll get further errors.

Comment: indeed!I replaced the names of the foreign keys so that they have a different name from the column name. I suppose I must be doing something wrong with the construction of weak entity. When I want to create a weak entity I just add in the weak entity's column the primary key of the strong entity it is dependent without making it primary key for the weak entity ,then I go to the FK tab on MySQL Workbench and I add that key with a different name as you said and make the necessary matching. Is what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using some software tool (SQL Workbench or some such thing) to do this so-called forward engineering. The way that generally works is that the tool cranks out SQL, and then passes it to your DBMS through a database connection.

Your tool is generating defective SQL data definition language (DDL) code.  That's not good. It's time to stop trusting the tool.

@Michael Berkowski diagnosed the defect in your DDL. You have `()` in a foreign key definition where MySQL's parser expects a column name.

Before you trash the tool completely, you might review how you have used it to define your relationships between entities. Those relationships translate into foreign keys when you forward-engineer your design into the database server. In your SQL look for the tables in which the foreign key definitions contain `()`. Those look like they may be the incorrectly designed relationships.

Pro tip.  On error 1064, the standard MySQL error message says something like this, always:

> ...for the right syntax to use near 'blah blah blah...

The text in single quotes *begins* with the first character of your SQL that MySQL did not understand. In your case it begins with `)`, meaning that some close parenthesis in your SQL caused the MySQL server to vomit.

Answer (score 0):

*Weak Entity:WE -
Strong Entity:SE -
Primary Key:PK -
Foreign Key:FK*

I was using MySQL Workbench and I didnt write code. mySQL Workbench did what I told it to do, but I instructed the wrong things, because I tried to create a WE the wrong way:

1. I ran the queries one at a time(as Sablefoste pointed out) and noticed    that only the WE had problem
2. I examined all the WE. On FK tab I used th same name for the FK and PK of the strong entity it depended.(as Michael Berkowski pointed out)
3. When I constructed the WE I defined the PK of the strong entity as the PK of the WE and then I went on the FK tab and made the standard matching between the WE's column and reference column. I shouldn't have defined it as PK of the WE the first place.

Problem solved.
thanks all for the help