# 1064 SQL workbench forward engineer error

Tags: mysql, sql

When i try to use the forward enginner function in sql workbench i get this error at the final step. Have any idea why?

Executing SQL script in server

```
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Account` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO AC' at line 13
SQL Code:

        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `mydb`.`ContactDetail`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`ContactDetail` (
          `ContactDetailId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
          `AccountId` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
          `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
          `FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
          `Sex` ENUM('male', 'female') NOT NULL COMMENT '',
          PRIMARY KEY (`ContactDetailId`)  COMMENT '',
          UNIQUE INDEX `ContactDetailId_UNIQUE` (`ContactDetailId` ASC)  COMMENT '',
          CONSTRAINT `AccountId`
            FOREIGN KEY ()
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`Account` ()
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

Comment: The `FOREIGN KEY ()` syntax is wrong -- you can't have an empty list there.

Comment: You mean that the generated code from the forward engineer is generating this code that seems to be erroneous. What version of SQL workbench are you using? There are some bug fixes relevant to forward engineer in v6.2.2.

Comment: my workbench version is 6.3 CE is that ok?

Comment: To be sure that your model has no missing or inconsistent objects, you may need to execute a schema validation process using the modelling tools/plugins. These tools are available under the "Model" menu. Please experiment with some tests and you may find some interesting points.

Comment: You may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32079950/3652270) answer useful.

Comment: Thanks for help, I Will chech monday

Comment: Still not solved, it seems that is a Workbench bug with foreignkey constraint